# What does 수면풍 and 자연풍 mean on my Korean fan settings?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage, korean-culture

Living in Korea, I’ve never really changed my standing fan setting other than the fan speed but I keep accidentally pressing the 바람모드 button and turning on “수면풍”, “자연풍” or “off”.
I couldn’t really find out what either setting really means and switching between each option just feels and sounds the same.
Anyone know what these setting names actually mean or what they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to one brand, 수면풍 and 자연풍 are modes that will cycle through different fan strengths over time.**

It appears one Korean blogger actually called the company (Cuchen) about these modes:
https://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=minjoo42&logNo=220444463451&proxyReferer=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

> [Natural Wind mode] generates wind ever so gentle, its refreshing
> touch on your skin will make you feel as though you are in a forest.
> Natural Wind mode will automatically change the wind strength in this
> order: 3-1-2-3-2-3-1-2, where 3 is high, 2 medium, and 1 low.

In the blog, it is said that 수면풍 (Bedtime wind mode) will change the wind strength in this order: 3-2-1-2-1-2, where 3 is high, 2 medium, and 1 low.

Comment: 자연풍, 수면풍, 너의 패턴은 이미 다 파악되었다. 강약중강중강약중, 강중약중약중

Answer (score 2):

수면풍 means 'bedtime mode' and '자연풍' means 'natural wind mode'.  Some products have both modes, some have only one, and cheap products don't have either. I guess 수면풍 is the mode with gentle breeze, not to interrupt deep sleep. 자연풍 is the mode with periodic various intensity to imitate natural breeze. I guess the fan you are using has both of two modes, but those tho are slightly different from each other in quality.